# Linking a javascript variable

Tags: javascript

How do I add a javascript variable in a link? The below code yields a blank page. viewData.php will contain PHP GET Variables to get the period and the type to determine whether I am pulling rental or sales amounts.  The period would be in the yyyymm format.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
init();
 });
 function init(){
 months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
 urls = ['http:/testServer/testPage/viewData.php?period=' + series.name + ''];

$.ajax({
url: 'readData.php'
}).done(function(data) {
    ar = data.split('###');
    for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
        ar[i] = ar[i].split('##');
    }
    for(var i=0;i<ar[0].length;i++){
        text = ar[0][i].split(' ').join('');
        year = text.substring(0,4);
        month = parseInt(text.split(year).join(''));
        month = months[month-1];
        ar[0][i] = month +','+year;
        ar[1][i] = parseFloat(ar[1][i]);
        ar[2][i] = parseFloat(ar[2][i]);
    }
    count = 0;
    dates = [];
    dates.push(ar[0][0]);
    for(var i=1;i<ar[0].length;i++){
        count++;

            dates.push(ar[0][i]);


    }
    dates[dates.length-1] = ar[0][dates.length-1];
    createGraph(ar,dates);
}); 
 }
   function createGraph(ar,dates){

        $('#60MonthAmount').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: "line"
                },

        title: {
            text: '60 Month Revenue by Location Chart'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Time Period'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                }
            },
            categories: dates,
            minTickInterval: 6,
            showLastLabel: true,


        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            min: 0,
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value / 1000000 +' mil';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/><p style="visibility: hidden;">_</p>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        if(this.x>urls.length){
                            url = urls[0];
                        }else{
                            url = urls[this.x];
                        }
                        window.open(url, '_blank');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Rentals',
            data: ar[1]
        }, {
            name: 'Sales',
            data: ar[2]
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: Gonna have to give us more to go on Dan. What is `series.name`? What is the code on `viewData.php` and how is `period` handled? ... and that's not a link...

Comment: The above creates an array with a single string in it; you need to show what you're actually *doing* with the variable. You'll also need to JS-escape the name.

Comment: If this is all the code you have, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @DaveNewton what do you mean by JS-escape the name?

Comment: I edited my initial post to include more information.

Comment: @RobertSadler I meant URL-encode; wasn't paying attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I add a javascript variable in a link?

I do not know what `series.name` is, however to make sure your URL is valid, you need to use `encodeURIComponent` on any of the url params so that they get properly encoded.

```
var url = 'http:/testServer/testPage/viewData.php?period=' + encodeURIComponent(series.name);
```